# How to make all numbers in a list of lists into just ints

Tags: python, list, casting

Say I have

```
A = [[1.0,2.3,1.1],[2.2,1.3,3.2]]
```

and I want to cast all of those numbers into just ints to have

```
A = [[1,2,1],[2,1,3]]
```

How do we do that in python?

Comment: If you want a solution that works for arbitrarily nested lists, use recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `list comprehension`*2:

```
print([[int(x) for x in i] for i in A])
```

Or `list comprehension` + `map`:

```
print([list(map(int,i)) for i in A])
```

Or `map`+`map`:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: list(map(int,x)),A)))
```

Simple ways all return:

```
[[1,2,1],[2,1,3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using a list comprehension and `map`:

```
A = [[1.0,2.3,1.1],[2.2,1.3,3.2]]
print([list(map(int, i)) for i in A])
```